# how set pagination of restful api in yii2?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

the result like these

```
{"id":19,"iso":"BB","name":"BARBADOS","nicename":"Barbados","iso3":"BRB","numcode":52,"phonecode":1246},{"id":20,"iso":"BY","name":"BELARUS","nicename":"Belarus","iso3":"BLR","numcode":112,"phonecode":375}]
 ,"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight/index?id=4FR996IN2F829Md&page=1"},"next":{"href":"http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight/index?id=4FR996IN2F829Md&page=2"},"last":{"href":"http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight/index?id=4FR996IN2F829Md&page=12"}},"_meta":
```

**{"totalCount":239,"pageCount":12,"currentPage":1,"perPage":20}}**

how change perPage or disable the pagination ???

**Updated!**

> set header content type but nothing effected!!

```
  X-Pagination-Per-Page: 90

-- response --
 200 OK
 Date:  Tue, 01 Sep 2015 12:29:45 GMT
 Server:  Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19
  X-Powered-By:  PHP/5.5.19
  X-Pagination-Total-Count:  239
  X-Pagination-Page-Count:  12
  X-Pagination-Current-Page:  1
  X-Pagination-Per-Page:  20

  Content-Length:  2421

  Keep-Alive:  timeout=5, max=100
    Connection:  Keep-Alive
   Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Results:

```
   {"results":           [{"id":1,"iso":"AF","name":"AFGHANISTAN","nicename":"Afghanistan","iso3":"AFG","numcode":4,"phonecode":93},
...
    {"id":20,"iso":"BY","name":"BELARUS","nicename":"Belarus","iso3":"BLR","numco    de":112,"phonecode":375}],_meta":  {"totalCount":239,"pageCount":12,"currentPage":1,"perPage":20}}
```

Comment: you need to handle `perPage` number ?? [Read this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html)

Comment: yes but how and how disable that?

Comment: you need to change value of that??

Comment: can you provide code which you tired so far

Comment: rest api automatically get response like that and i want to change pagination of that but idon't know how!!!

Comment: My implementation can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34380863/1437261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You can change per page value by modifying HTTP header X-Pagination-Per-Page</strike>

Check docs for more information [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#collections)

**Update1:**
Sorry, I hurried up and posted incorrect answer. Below is the way how to change page size. You need to look at [ActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#active-data-provider) - it has *$pagination* property (you can read about it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html)). Setting [$pageSize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$pageSize-detail) or [$defaultPageSize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$defaultPageSize-detail) to the value you need should work.

Comment: @mohsen I think, in the request that gives that response, ask for the user to send you what they want, e.g how many items the want per page, then before you run the query, process the request parameter, and in the query, set the `$pageSize` to what the user requested to in the call.

If this doesn't make sense, share code you have  and I show you a sample.

Comment: thanks @Sammie i did that you can see the request and response of updated part of the question !!!

Answer (score 13):

I know this question is old but all across the internet I see a lot of bad advice about achieving this when it's simple using the REST API per-page param. This is a two part answer.

1. How change perPage or disable the pagination ???

First you have to specify the page param in the url not in the header. Look at how the gridview changes the url when using the CRUD generator.

For instance. Here's a url that will return 10 items per response

http://www.example.com?per-page=10

This url will return 50

http://www.example.com?per-page=50

Here's the catch. The default pagination only goes up to 50. See here:https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$pageSizeLimit-detail. If you want more than 50 records, you'll have to change this param in your pagination like this:

```
$query = SampleModel::find();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        pageSizeLimit = [1, 1000]
    ]
]);
```

Now you can specify up anywhere from 1-1000 records per page.

2. This wasn't part of the question but it's pertinent. Since you're into pagination, how do you cycle through the pages. You get the response headers to see exactly how many pages are available. They're located in the custom headers the Yii2 Rest API provides

X-Pagination-Current-Page →1

X-Pagination-Page-Count →2

X-Pagination-Per-Page →100

X-Pagination-Total-Count →157

In order to pick a page you still have to specify it in the url. This is page 2 out of 157 records with 30 records per page.

http://www.example.com?page=2&per-page=30

Here's the response headers:

X-Pagination-Current-Page →2

X-Pagination-Page-Count →6

X-Pagination-Per-Page →30

X-Pagination-Total-Count →157

FINALLY if you're set on returning ALL of your records which no one should ever do, You can set your pageSizeLimit floor to zero like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        pageSizeLimit = [0, 1000]
    ]
]);
```

Then specify the per-page as 0.

http://www.example.com?per-page=0

This will return all the records.

Here's the header response for all the records

X-Pagination-Current-Page →1

X-Pagination-Page-Count →1

X-Pagination-Per-Page →0

X-Pagination-Total-Count →157

Again, no one should ever do this. You should cycle through the pagination to build your array but this is crazy talk. What if you have over a million records? Anyhow, it's your project. Good Luck to anyone in 2018 looking at this since it isn't exactly spelled out in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to yii2 documentation for the serializing of the data
It will paginate the data for you in the response

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-pagination

You can use this code snippet as well in you controller class

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];
}
```

This will be the response format

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 05:31:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.20 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.20
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 1000
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 50
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20
Link: <http://localhost/users?page=1>; rel=self,
      <http://localhost/users?page=2>; rel=next,
      <http://localhost/users?page=50>; rel=last
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=1"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=2"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=50"
        }
    },
    "_meta": {
        "totalCount": 1000,
        "pageCount": 50,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "perPage": 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

code like below:

```
    $query = SampleModel::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'defaultPageSize' => 2, //set page size here
        ]
    ]);
    $relationShips = $dataProvider->getModels();
```