# Yii2 data provider for rest api call

Tags: api, rest, pagination, yii2, dataprovider

Currently I'm using the `yii2 array dataprovider` for listing the datas from rest api. We have more than 10k records. Each rest api call can get only `maximum 100 records`, If we want more i need to give the limit and offset for this rest api call.

Is there any specific rest api dataprovider in yii2? else how can i implement pagination for this rest API?

Comment: You Can use `ActiveDataProvider` or `SqlDataProvider` ...

Comment: How can i pass the rest api call in ActiveDataProvier query param.. Please is there any sample

Answer (score 0):

`dataprovider`, in `Yii2` has support for pagination. Suppose, your service receives it's params with the following code:

```
$params = Yii::$app->getRequest()->post();
```

You could include `page` parameter in the request, and then do a little hack (:P), like :

```
if (isset($params ['page'])) {
    $_GET['page'] = (int) $params ['page'];
    if ($_GET['page'] < 1) {
        $_GET['page'] = 1;
    }
}
```

Once you do that, your `dataprovider` automatically assigns the value of `$_GET` to it's result set. An example of dataprovider:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Users::find(),
    'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 10),
        ]);
```

Or, in your case:

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $query->from('post')->all(),
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['id', 'username', 'email'],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
        ]);
```

To get the models, you could use `getModels()` method of `dataprovider` like following:

```
$models = $dataProvider->getModels();
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.